# Remover somente elementos numéricos de um array

Tags: php

Tenho um *array* desta forma:

```
$arr = array('prolongar-se', 'durante, 4, 'a', 7, 'dias', 
    'dependendo', 'da', 'dose', 'administrada', 'e', 'do', 
    'pH', 'da', 'água', 'sendo', 7.5, 'ml', 'por','cada','paciente');
```

Gostaria de remover os valores numéricos `4`, `7` e `7.5`, e retornasse desta forma abaixo:

```
$arr = array('prolongar-se', 'durante, 'a', 'dias', 'dependendo', 
    'da', 'dose', 'administrada', 'e', 'do', 'pH', 'da', 'água', 
    'sendo', 'ml', 'por','cada','paciente');
```

Como posso remover elementos do tipo numérico de um *array*?

Comment: Não quis postar uma resposta falando a respeito, porque não cabe ao caso, mas depois dê uma pesquisada na função `preg_grep`. Eu gosto dela porque ela retorna os elementos do `array` que casam com a expressão regular passada!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-filter.php), por exemplo:

```
$arr = array('prolongar-se', 'durante', 4, 'a', 7, 'dias', 
    'dependendo', 'da', 'dose', 'administrada', 'e', 'do', 
    'pH', 'da', 'água', 'sendo', 7.5, 'ml', 'por','cada','paciente');

function remover_numero($string) {

    return !is_numeric($string);

}

$arr = array_filter($arr, 'remover_numero');
```

O `array_filter` espera um retorno de `true` ou `false`, no caso de `false` ele remove o valor da array. No caso de `true` ele mantem. Dessa forma o `remover_numero` faz o trabalho de verificar se é ou não um número e então retornar `true` se não for numérico ou `false` se for numérico.

Você também pode utilizar algo do tipo: `array_filter($arr, function($string) { return !is_numeric($string); })` que terá o mesmo efeito.

---

**Resultado:**

```
array(18) {
  [0]=>
  string(12) "prolongar-se"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "durante"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [5]=>
  string(4) "dias"
  [6]=>
  string(10) "dependendo"
  [7]=>
  string(2) "da"
  [8]=>
  string(4) "dose"
  [9]=>
  string(12) "administrada"
  [10]=>
  string(1) "e"
  [11]=>
  string(2) "do"
  [12]=>
  string(2) "pH"
  [13]=>
  string(2) "da"
  [14]=>
  string(5) "água"
  [15]=>
  string(5) "sendo"
  [17]=>
  string(2) "ml"
  [18]=>
  string(3) "por"
  [19]=>
  string(4) "cada"
  [20]=>
  string(8) "paciente"
}
```

---

[**Teste isto!**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ba011bd09c60e084075f07c720397b07a09a5a0c)

Comment: É forma legal de resolver meu problema. Existe alguma alternativa nesta mesma linha de raciocínio para não remover valores que estejam como *string* por exemplo: `"8"`?

Comment: Se quer apenas remover se for `int` ou `float` pode utilizar a resposta do [@Wallace Maxters](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/187936/15089), que remove tudo que não for `string`. O `is_numeric` vai remover mesmo se for `string`.

Answer (score 3):

Se no seu caso, os números que estiverem presentes no `array` sempre forem `int` ou `float` (e não um número dentro de uma `string`), você pode fazer de forma mais simples ainda:

```
$sem_numeros = array_filter($arr, 'is_string');
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer uso da função [unset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) do php para remover os elementos do vetor, mas antes de remover, você precisa verificar se o elemento é um número, uma string numérica ou apenas uma string, para isso, você pode usar a função [is_numeric](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) e por último, você precisa "reindexar" o vetor, já que a função [unset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) remove um elemento do vetor e deixa um "buraco", para isso, você pode usar a função [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) que vai retornar todos os valores do vetor e vai indexá-lo numericamente.

PS: Se você não quiser remover as strings numéricas do vetor, como: "42", "20"..., você precisará trocar a função [is_numeric](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) por [is_int](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php) e [is_float](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-float.php)

```
function removeNumberFromArray(&$array) {

    foreach($array as $key => $item) {
        if(is_numeric($item)) {
            unset($array[$key]);
        }
    }

    $array = array_values($array);
}
```

Comment: Amigão, realmente acha necessário escrever tanto código para fazer uma operação simples assim?  O PHP conta com algumas funções que podem facilitar esse tipo de operação. Usar o `unset` dentro de um `foreach` pode prejudicar a performance, dependendo do tamanho do `array`.

Comment: Necessário não é, as outras respostas mostram isso. Mas tem seu valor didático. E é sempre bom ter respostas alternativas.

Comment: Sim, concordo com você Wallace, mas se o programador iniciante não sabe como remover os elementos do vetor, ele não conhece todas as funções que abordei em minha resposta, como: unset, is_numeric, is_int, is_float, array_values e também a passagem de valor por referência, sem contar que ele vai precisar ter um pensamento estruturado para organizar tudo isso. Resumindo, isso tudo vai agregar mais conhecimento a ele. E por isso é uma resposta alternativa.